# How to encode strings inside serial number using PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, serial-port

I need to generate serial numbers using PHP in the following format "ASDK3-JDAL9-24SFT-J5D8R-D4AL9". One requirement is the fact that I need to encode somehow a timestamp and an email address inside this serial number and then retrieve them when needed. Is there any easy way to do this?

**EDIT**
To be more specific the allowed numbers and letters in serial number need to be 0-9 and A-Z. To make it more generic I need to have 2 short strings for example encoded in that serial number. For example a date "04/03/2013" and one number "324" or email address if possible. The string don't need to be human readable in the serial number but I need to be able to retrieve them when needed.

Comment: There is, but I'm afraid you don't have enough space for a whole e-mail address.  E-mail addresses can be very long!  You would be better off storing that data somewhere.  Also, this gets much easier if that serial number can just be a hash.  Are you sure you actually need the store that ID and e-mail address?  Or can you just validate that this serial is associated with it?

Comment: I think I can get rid of the email address, but I still need a timestamp and a small number (3 digits max). Is this possible?

Comment: can you be more specific about the allowed numbers and digits in the serial number. Also, when you say you want email and timestamp encoded into the serial number, do you mean they should be a literal part of the s/n or they should be the basis on which the s/n is generated? Also, where is this "small number" coming from all of a sudden? Make sure to include your requirements right from the start. Also, have you tried anything already and can you show what you got so far?

Comment: I just edited my question to make it more specific. I got nothing so far. I found ways to generate a random serial number but I couldn't find anything that allows you to encode some info inside it. The number I was referring is a user id I get from database because is shorter than a email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do some simple math using base32 encode. You have 36 characters but we'll assume 32 because we're doing a rough estimate.

Base 32 adds 60% overhead. If you want to store a date of 8 characters and a number of 3 characters you'll need at least: `( 8 + 3 ) * 1.6 = 18` characters for this data. Your key is 25 characters long so you'll have `7 / 1.6 = 4` characters left for some randomness. If your random keys have 64 characters you'll have `64^4 = 16 million` possibilities.

PHP doesn't have a native base 32 function available but you can write one yourself, the outline is the same as base64 except you take 7 bits at a time instead of 8.

Comment: I think is a great idea. I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416802/effective-solution-base32-encoding-in-php