# Generating Google2fa secrets based on a fixed string

Tags: laravel, two-factor-authentication

We're building a system to validate mobile phone numbers.
To achieve this, when a user adds his number, we are sending him a text message with a 6 digit code.

We don't want this code to go in our database as we don't like to clutter our database with fields that have no business meaning.

So we came up with the idea to reuse `pragmarx/google2fa`library, have it generate an OTP code, dispatch it to the user by a text message, and then the circle would be round.

So basically we wanted to use the phone number, prefixed by somehting secret as the "secret" for the `pragmarx/google2fa` library:

```
$secret = '1263' . $mobile->country_code . $mobile->subscriber;

$google2fa = new Google2FA();
$google2fa->setEnforceGoogleAuthenticatorCompatibility(false);

$google2fa->getCurrentOtp($secret);
```

The above results in a `secret`similar to `12633232970987`.  However, the call to `getCurrentOtp` throws an exception `Invalid characters in the base32 string.` which is obviously not what I was hoping for.

So, I tried adding

```
$secret = base_convert($secret, 10, 32)
```

and pass that to the `getCurrentOtp`method, but that returned the same error.  Checking into the library code, I see the following constant:

```
const VALID_FOR_B32 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567';
```

My base_convert returns a string that has other characters in there though.  Are these really the only valid characters?

My alternative would be to just have the library generate a random secret, but we don't really want to do that, as that would require us to keep that secret somewhere in the database (or at least in cache), which we would like to avoid.  The idea is that we could generate the code for a mobile number using the number as the secret, and let the OTP mechanism deal with expiring codes.

Anyone has any suggestion how I can resolve this?

Comment: Are the other characters you are finding in the string "="? If so, you should strip those out too.

Comment: Nope - they just contain 0, for instance.

Comment: Oh! You’re converting numbers from base 10 to base 32. It should be a string encoding conversion instead. I’m on a train otherwise I’d write a better answer, but check this question for ways to base32 encode strings in php: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416802/effective-solution-base32-encoding-in-php

Comment: Seriously - not sure how I oversaw that.  You pointed me into the right direction.  Apparently, `pragmarx\google2fa` does expose a method `->toBase32()` which I can use.  This solved my issue.  Put it as an answer, and I'll be happy to accept!